# Unable to send smtp emails in C# with a VMware vm of win 7

Tags: c#, smtp, gmail, vmware

the VMware is able to ping the gmail server.

sample code

---

```
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            SmtpClient SmtpServer = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
            mail.From = new MailAddress("fromxyz@gmail.com");
            mail.To.Add("to");
            mail.Subject = "subjct";
            mail.Body = "email body!!";

            System.Net.Mail.Attachment attachment;
            attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment("filename.extension");
            mail.Attachments.Add(attachment);

            SmtpServer.Port = 587;
            SmtpServer.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("email id", "password");
            SmtpServer.EnableSsl = true;

            SmtpServer.Send(mail);
```

---

I have got it has something to do with ports being open on vmware some networking issue, but i just can't put a finger on it. Please let know what it is that i am doing wrong.
Thnx - Egon

---

update : image: [image]

---

update 2 :

here are the exception details :

**System.Net.Mail.SmtpException was unhandled
  Message="Failure sending mail."
  Source="System"
  StackTrace:
       at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)**

```
   at Search_Main.Rating_Result.sendIt() in C:\Users\cloud\Desktop\demo\demo\Search_Main0\Search_Main\Search_Main\Rating_Result.xaml.cs:line 98
   at Search_Main.Rating_Result.ShareTOAll(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) in C:\Users\cloud\Desktop\demo\demo\Search_Main0\Search_Main\Search_Main\Rating_Result.xaml.cs:line 143
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnClick()
   at System.Windows.Controls.Button.OnClick()
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseLeftButtonUpThunk(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object genericTarget)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.ReRaiseEventAs(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args, RoutedEvent newEvent)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.CrackMouseButtonEventAndReRaiseEvent(DependencyObject sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseUpThunk(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object genericTarget)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean trusted)
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(InputEventArgs input)
   at System.Windows.Input.InputProviderSite.ReportInput(InputReport inputReport)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.ReportInput(IntPtr hwnd, InputMode mode, Int32 timestamp, RawMouseActions actions, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 wheel)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.FilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.InputFilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WrappedInvoke(Delegate callback, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter, Delegate catchHandler)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.InvokeImpl(DispatcherPriority priority, TimeSpan timeout, Delegate method, Object args, Boolean isSingleParameter)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority priority, Delegate method, Object arg)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
   at MS.Win32.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessage(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(DispatcherFrame frame)
   at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Run()
   at System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(Object ignore)
   at System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(Window window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run(Window window)
   at System.Windows.Application.Run()
   at Search_Main.App.Main() in C:\Users\cloud\Desktop\demo\demo\Search_Main0\Search_Main\Search_Main\obj\Debug\App.g.cs:line 0
   at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(Assembly assembly, String[] args)
   at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

**InnerException: System.Net.WebException
       Message="Unable to connect to the remote server"

```
   Source="System"**
   StackTrace:
        at System.Net.ServicePoint.GetConnection(PooledStream PooledStream, Object owner, Boolean async, IPAddress& address, Socket& abortSocket, Socket& abortSocket6, Int32 timeout)
        at System.Net.PooledStream.Activate(Object owningObject, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback)
        at System.Net.PooledStream.Activate(Object owningObject, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback)
        at System.Net.ConnectionPool.GetConnection(Object owningObject, GeneralAsyncDelegate asyncCallback, Int32 creationTimeout)
        at System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.GetConnection(String host, Int32 port)
        at System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.GetConnection(String host, Int32 port)
        at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.GetConnection()
        at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)


   **InnerException: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException
        Message="No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 74.125.95.109:587"
        Source="System"**
        ErrorCode=10061
        NativeErrorCode=10061
        StackTrace:
             at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
             at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.InternalConnect(EndPoint remoteEP)
             at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Int32 timeout, Exception& exception)
        InnerException:
```

Comment: Can you show the inner exception please

Comment: We really need to see the Detail... of the SmtpException. As the Troubleshooting tips suggest, the Response or Status properties may hold the clue as to how to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If port 587 isn't working (which is the port for TLS/STARTTLS) try 465 (Port for SSL).

http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=13287

Comment: this is not the issue. Can you suggest something else, I have posted the exception image. thank you

Answer (score 2):

2 quick things:

1. check the inner exception(s) of the thrown exception.
2. Enable logging on the System.Net.Mail object. See 
   http://systemnetmail.com/faq/4.10.aspx